# Angular2 vs jQuery: Can jQuery actually cancel angular's bindings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

So first, before you bite my head off, I would NEVER use jQuery in an angular project... never ever... but the client really wants it even if strongly objecting...

**AND for future readers... NEVER use jquery on Angular project... there is NO need**

Now, that we cleared that up :)

Angular(2) app binds some default click events to some links / buttons...

The clients wants to be able to overwrite the events  with jQuery...

this is the pretty standard jQuery code I put in

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on("click", '.b-button button', function (event) {
        console.log( "clicked!" );
        console.log(event);
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
});
```

While the event is triggered, it seems I cannot cancel it or prevent propagation... angular2 still takes over

what would be the proper way?

for the reference, using 3.2.1 slim version of jQuery

Comment: NEVER use jquery on Angular project!

Comment: I hope this client is paying you well :p

Comment: well, yeah... nice long contract for 10 months, nice daily rate... and project finished... my last couple of days... just handing it off... and ironing these last bits and client's wishes ;)